# Why iPhone is not available. Please reconnect the device error showing? Xcode 12.2 iOS 14.4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have macOS installed is 10.15.7
My Xcode version is 12.2.
My iPhone iOS is 14.4
I can't run the app on my iPhone also can not find device support files for iPhone iOS 14.4.
I am using mid 2012 MacBook Pro so I can't upgrade to latest Xcode versions.
Can you please help me to solve this?
Below is the screenshot of error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think support for 14.4 was added in Xcode 12.4, Xcode 12.2 supports iOS up to 12.2.

See: https://xcodereleases.com

Comment: You can try to use this workaround, which lets you add support files for newer iOS into older Xcode versions: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport I have no experience with it though, but collegues say it works

Comment: Glad it helped.